# How to add a Podfile to an existing xcode swift static lib project .xcodeproj?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I want to add the Podfile below to my Swift static lib project.

I built the Podfile by creating an empty project, and then did:

```
pod init  
pod install  
(added my lines into Podfile)  
pod update
```

Now I want to add this Podfile into my existing static lib proj so that it can run the ONNX runtime, which, I believe, the project would now automatically download from the Internet.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'KP_to_iOS_5' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for KP_to_iOS_5
  pod 'onnxruntime-mobile-c'  # mobile package
  pod 'onnxruntime-mobile-objc'  # mobile package

end
```